# iOS : Store offline podcast audio file in core data by using swift 4

Tags: ios, core-data, avfoundation, swift4

I am using core data to store offline podcast audio files and I am having around 200 audio files to storing offline but app getting stuck when my app newly launched.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I am using offline and online also

Answer (score 0):

You can save your file in Data type with `Allow External Storage` options. It will keep your `managed context` load more faster

[image: Setting like this]

Comment: I am storing multiple attributes of data into core data that time UI getting stuck after saving it.

Comment: @iHarshad: You can save it in background. In the main thread, you can so the progress view or whatever